# How to response json from webserver and don't show them onto webpage on Webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have an api that return a json string.
An ashx file

```
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        string result = string.Empty;
        result = "{\"status\": \"OK\"}";
        context.Response.Write(result);
     }
```

I want to hidden the string {"status": "OK"} on webpage response and the client can get this string.

Thanks.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get the string to the client code you can convert it to a javascript object, erase the attributes you don't want and stringify again to show it.

You can also strip the text you don't want by using string manipulation methods, however I think the first approach is more elegant.